# How To Check What Apps Is Eating My CPU

Tags: lagging, cpu

My device is so laggy so I downloaded CPU - Z to check my CPU

and I see 50 - 70% CPU load

I tried Cache deleting and RAM Cleaning but it's still using a lot of CPU

Are there any Add-ons so I can see which of my apps are Using my CPU?

*sorry my grammar, English isn't my first language*

Device: Samsung Tab 4

Model: SM-T231

Rooted: Yes

Busybox: Installed

Comment: Without knowing which device you have and what android version it is on and further if it's rooted and xposed is installed or not, chances of getting answers are very low, so do add above mentioned details

Comment: There are several tools available for [system monitoring](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_systeminfo) (link goes to my own Android site). For "quick glances" I'd say take a look at "OS Monitor", which gives you very useful details also in other cases.

Comment: I added my device information